# Databricks not displaying correct output

Tags: filter, where-clause, azure-databricks, display

In Azure databricks I am applying a filter to show the data where Region column has value 'weu'.

```
display(df.where(col("Region") == 'weu'))
```

But the output dataframe I am getting has Region values as eus & sea.
Can anyone help why is this happening?

Comment: filtered_df = df.where(lower(col("Region")) == "weu")
Can you try this ?

Comment: Tried it but still the result is same. Region column has all values in small alphabets.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input data

Comment: I tried with trim too but same result. Unfortunately not possible for me to share data due to data security.

Output of df.select(lower(col("Region"))).distinct().show() is:

+-------------+
|lower(Region)|
+-------------+
|          eus|
|          sea|
|          weu|
+-------------+

Comment: Ok can you try this from pyspark.sql.functions import col, ascii

display(df.where(ascii(col("Region")) == 'weu'))using the ascii() function to convert the Region column to its ASCII representation and then apply the filter

Comment: from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lower, regexp_replace

display(df.where(lower(regexp_replace(col("Region"), "\s+", "")) == 'weu'))

I think there are wite space can you also check the above

Comment: Not giving any output now.

Comment: ASCII value for eus=101, sea=115, and weu=119

I tried this:
display(df.where(ascii(col("Region")) == 101))
display(df.where(ascii(col("Region")) == 115))
display(df.where(ascii(col("Region")) == 119))

but output dataframe only has eus & sea values in all cases.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/4EFPOXG.png
I have tried this and it worked

Comment: from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace

display(df.where(regexp_replace(col("Region"), "[^ -~]+", "") == 'weu'))

Comment: Tried this too but no luck. anyways thank you so much for all these suggestions.

Comment: with out the input data it would not be possible to understand the issue.
It would be helpful if you can provide sample data.
also can you share the screen shot of the results that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I have used some sample data like below:

```
Region  Value
weu      1
eus      2
sea      3
```

The reason you are seeing region values as **eus** & **sea** Because containing values with leading and trailing white spaces.

I have tried the below approach:

Filter the DataFrame based on the Region column, applying the `trim()` function to remove any leading or trailing white spaces before filtering.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, trim
filtered_df = dilip_df.where(trim(col("Region")) ==  "weu")
display(filtered_df)
```

[image]

Also you can check:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower
dilip_df.select(lower(col("Region"))).distinct().show()
```

From the **dilip_df** DataFrame, `select` the Region column. Convert all the values in the column to lowercase using the `lower()` function, and then return only the distinct values in the column using the `distinct()` function.